# SharePoint 2010 - How to link directly to a document through XSLT?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, xslt

I have exported a content query web part which is looking at a document library. The items appear correctly. The web part was exported to generate a custom appearance. When clicking on the document title, I want it to link directly to the document to download. The below does not seem to be working.

```
<xsl:template name="document-items">     
    <a href="{@FileRef}">
       <span class="item-title"><xsl:value-of select="@FileLeafRef"/></span>
    </a>
 </xsl:template>
```

or..

```
<xsl:template name="document-items">     
<a href="{substring-before(@FileRef, ', ')}">
   <span class="item-title"><xsl:value-of select="@FileLeafRef"/></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolved. After fiddling around, I noticed the @FileRef was producing an additional extension of the URL onto the original. Therefore I added the following code:

```
 <a href="www.yoururlhere.com/{@FileRef}>
<xsl:value-of select="@FileLeafRef"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it.  With icon and document without the extension.

```
  <xsl:template name="DocLib" match="Row[@Style='DocLib']" mode="itemstyle">
<xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl"><xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
<xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle">
<xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
<xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title"/>
<xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="LinkTarget">
<xsl:if test="@OpenInNewWindow = 'True'" >_blank</xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
<div >
<xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate"/>
<a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" title="{@LinkToolTip}">
<xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams = 'True'">
                   <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                     <xsl:value-of select="@OnClickForWebRendering"/>
                   </xsl:attribute>
                 </xsl:if>
                 <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams != 'True' and @OpenInNewWindow = 'True'">
                   <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                     <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$OnClickTargetAttribute"/>
                   </xsl:attribute>
                 </xsl:if> 
                 <img class="image" src="{@DocumentIconImageUrl}" title="" />&#160;&#160;<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(string(@FileLeafRef),'.')" />
                 </a></div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi tron instead of downloading document when clicked can i know how to make it to take me to the location of file. I am not getting it tried ways using fileleafref.Thanks in advance